# Floating button between action bar and Frame Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, floating

I want something like this:

[image]

I have the following now:

[image]

With the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/book_detail">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I have some problems:

1. The Title is on top instead of bottom
2. There's something like a separator on top

I'm using a coordinator now, but I don't need a collapsing toolbar, so I think that there must be another solution maybe. How can I solve this?

Comment: How about using [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first start by making the toolbar taller. I think what you're looking for is [CollapingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout)

To use the CollapsingToolbarLayout you have to change your `ConstraintLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`.
Then you have to create an `AppBarLayout` to hold the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the `Toolbar`.

Then to make the floating button in that place you have to anchor it to the `AppBarLayout` created earlier like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/message" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        app:elevation="30dp"/>
```

That way it will be anchored to the `AppBarLayout` so it will go up and down as the `AppBarLayout` goes up or down.

**EDIT #1** :

To remove the title from the top and remove the separator you have to set your activity's theme to `NoActionBar`. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file go to your activity and change its code to the following:

```
<activity
        android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY_PATH.BookDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

This way the activity will be declared without an action bar which means no separator and no title.

Then to add the title to the bottom you just have to set the title of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to the text you want.

You can set it in the xml with `app:title="YOUR_TITLE"` attribute or you can set it programmatically by calling the function `setTitle("YOUR_TITLE")` for your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` variable .

Here is what the **full code** could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BookDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:title="YOUR_TITLE"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" 
        android:id="@+id/book_detail">
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/message" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        app:elevation="30dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**:

In your activity set your action bar by this : 
`setSupportActionBar(YOUR_TOOLBAR_VARIABLE)` then you can use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Note that the toolbar should be the id of this one: 
`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` so in our case the toolbar with the id `toolbar`

Comment: @Lechucico I've edited the answer to solve your new problems, check and tell me if any other problem happened

Comment: This solved everything, minus one thing! I've lost the arrow (back button) from top, because now this activity doesn't have ActionBar. How I can set the back button? I've inserted this with `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

The use this class for action of FAB

```
public class FlexibleSpaceExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    private static final int PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_IMAGE = 20;
    private View mFab;
    private int mMaxScrollSize;
    private boolean mIsImageHidden;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flexible_space);

        mFab = findViewById(R.id.flexible_example_fab);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.flexible_example_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.flexible_example_appbar);
        appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        if (mMaxScrollSize == 0)
            mMaxScrollSize = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();

        int currentScrollPercentage = (Math.abs(i)) * 100
            / mMaxScrollSize;

        if (currentScrollPercentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_IMAGE) {
            if (!mIsImageHidden) {
                mIsImageHidden = true;

                ViewCompat.animate(mFab).scaleY(0).scaleX(0).start();
                /**
                * Realize your any behavior for FAB here!
                **/
            }
        }

        if (currentScrollPercentage < PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_IMAGE) {
            if (mIsImageHidden) {
                mIsImageHidden = false;
                ViewCompat.animate(mFab).scaleY(1).scaleX(1).start();
                /**
                * Realize your any behavior for FAB here!
                **/
            }
        }
    }

    public static void start(Context c) {
        c.startActivity(new Intent(c, FlexibleSpaceExampleActivity.class));
    }
}
```

There are some **Github** Implementation to develope this view and many other

[Collapsing Toolbar with Fab](https://github.com/arsan-official/collapsing-toolbar)

Comment: This example crashes when trying to use

Comment: What is error can you share error log @Lechucico. Did you set COnstraintLayout as parent layout

Comment: First of all, this example doesn't contain any constraint for using constraintLayout.

Comment: Yes but you can use other parent as you need maybe an Coordinate Layout, LinearLayout or Relative.  Please provide error log so I can tell what an issues @Lechucico